# React Native new Date() not working

Tags: javascript, datetime, react-native

I tried to get `Date` from `datestring` but it's not wokring properly.

```
var time = new Date('2017-12-26T02:12:00')
```

But when I called `time.getHours()` it returns `12`.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: That's because of timezones.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  What I have to do to get exact hour?

Comment: You can make use of getUTCHours() and getTimezoneOffset()

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Adding below code fixed the problem

```
time.setMinutes(time.getMinutes() + time.getTimezoneOffset());
```

:)

Answer (score -2):

Use below code to get day, month and year.

```
var date = new Date(),
    day = date.getDate(),
    month = date.getMonth() + 1,
    year = date.getFullYear(),
    today = day+"-"+month+"-"+year;
```

You can change the format of date as per your requirement.